# Arduino Matrix Math?

Tags: c++, matrix, arduino, arduino-uno

I'm looking for a library that can handle matrix math on the Arduino. I know that there is one library featured on the [Arduino Playground](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/MatrixMath), but I've found it to be a little lackluster in it's inability to handle poorly conditioned matrices, as well as its user interface is a little kludgy.

Are there any alternatives? Preferably ones that have some sort of reputation, like Armadillo or PETsc? I'd love to use one of the big ones, but it seems they've all moved on to C++11, which isn't yet supported by the Arduino IDE. My other option is to update avr-gcc to the latest, use Atmel Studio/Visual Studio, and build things myself. Then I should be able to use one of these other, mature libraries. I'd prefer not to have to go down that rabbit hole, especially since the Arduino core isn't guaranteed to work with C++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BAM!

`eigen` the best c++ matrix library has an arduino port!

https://github.com/vancegroup/EigenArduino

Comment: Nice! I'll check it out and see how it works. Thanks!

Comment: So, it requires your own version of stdlib, i.e. [stlport-avr](https://github.com/vancegroup/stlport-avr/blob/STLport-master-avr/INSTALL) I'm too tired to run through that compile tonight, I'll get to it tomorrow and report back.

Comment: @gankoji I knew of `eigen` and when i found a port I thought this would be really good. TBH i think you should be careful because the overhead of `stl` and `eigen` might fill up your avr chips memory.

Answer (score 2):

It works! Ran through a simple program this AM to test:

```
#include <stlport.h>
#include <Eigen30.h>

using Eigen::MatrixXd;

MatrixXd m(2, 2);

void setup()
{
     Serial.begin(115200);

  /* add setup code here */
     m(0, 0) = 3;
     m(1, 0) = 2.5;
     m(0, 1) = -1;
     m(1, 1) = m(1, 0) + m(0, 1);

}

void loop()
{

  /* add main program code here */
     Serial.println(m(1,1));
     delay(2000);
}
```

You're right about bloat, though, as this sketch was >5 KB.

Comment: And bloat has come back to bite me. My code was roughly 20 kB before using Eigen and stlport-avr (and using the MatrixMath library from Arduino Playground), but now it's 33.6! Can't upload it to my poor Uno...

Comment: Yeah, that is pretty much the downside of c++ in general on AVR devices. `eigen` is a fantastic library, probably the best Matrix lib IMO but it will carry a lot of overhead.

Comment: Luckily, I had a Mega sitting around, which has 256k of flash. Debugging it now, hopefully I'll get some results to share soon.

Comment: One more update: Eigen is now working quite well, the filter running without trouble. Total code size is up to about 44-45 k, and the main loop is running at about 530 ms (with all the debugging output still turned on), so I think the performance is pretty good. Thanks again for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

I like [BasicLinearAlgebra](https://github.com/tomstewart89/BasicLinearAlgebra/). It's well documented, supports matrices of different types (floats, ints) and sparse matrices, but it's very tiny.